# Value type and ref type

Tags: c#

I have summarized my problem in following code snippet.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication13
{
    public class Student
    {
        public int Marks { get; set; }
        public Student(int marks)
        {
            this.Marks = marks;

        }
        public void AssignMarks(Student st)
        {
            st = null;
        }
        public void AssignMarks(ref Student st)
        {
            st = null;
        }
    }
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Student st = new Student(50);
            st.AssignMarks(st);
            Console.WriteLine(st.Marks);
            Student st1 = new Student(50);
            st.AssignMarks(ref st1); // NullReferenceException
            Console.WriteLine(st1.Marks);
        }
    }
}
```

Why am  I getting NullReferenceException exception on the line marked with the **

Comment: well, the type of exception might help

Comment: I have edited my question.I am getting NullReferenceException

Comment: You *should* be getting an NRE on the line `Console.WriteLine(st1.Marks);`, as `st1` will be null at that point.

Comment: Might want to check out: http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/parameters.html

Comment: Since you are in C# I am going to assume you are running VS, but regardless of that; Debugging, hitting F5 in VS, would have identified this problem instantly.

Comment: on the ** line, why do you use 'st.A..' instead of 'st1.A..'?

Comment: @santosh, why would you expect an exception in the second code snippet? You're not doing anything exceptional (nor are you doing anything that benefits from a `ref` modifier).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're actually getting the exception on the `WriteLine` call.,  (I tried it)

Because `st1` is passed `ref`, the variable that you pass becomes `null`.

A `ref` parameter is a reference to a *variable*, not a reference to an object.
Therefore, if a method changes its `ref` parameter to point to a different object, the variable whose reference was passed will be changed.

Comment: +1 for providing a deeper explanation. As some like to phrase it, the `ref` parameter acts like an *alias* for the original variable at the call site.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you're not getting a `NullReferenceException` on the line below (as I am seeing)?

This is caused by the reference st1 being set to null in the body of `AssignMarks(ref Student st)`.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting NullReferenceException on the next line (`Console.WriteLine(st1.Marks);`) because st1 is null after executing `AssignMarks(ref Student st1)`

Answer (score 1):

You should read about ValueType/Reference Type and Stack/Heap.

Here, Student is a reference type, so your object is stored in Heap.
The pointer to this object lies in Stack (since it is a variable).

"Method - 1"

When you pass the object in first method (without ref), you are sending the pointer which points to some address in Heap (again, since Student is of reference type). This pointer is "copied" to the argument and is local to the method only.
Now the method can access to that memory location and "change" the value stored in that address.

As Below,

```
public void AssignMarks(Student st)
        {
            st.Marks=100;
        }
```

In this case, WriteLine in Program.Main method will pring 100 !!!

Coming back to your first method. The pointer is "copied" in the argument of your method.
By doing, `'st = null'`, this local copy points to "new" memory location in Heap, and the original memory location remains as it is.
Thus, when the call returns back. Your object remains same.

"Method - 2"

On the other hand, when you pass this argument as '`ref`', it is actually sending pointer to your original variable (behavior remains same for ValyeType and ReferenceType).
In this case, the method has access to the memory location of the variable itself (not to the value it is pointing to). So, if the method changes anything in this argument, it is reflected as-is in the calling method.
Has to be, right? In all sense it is the same memory location being accessed from different places and different variables.

Since you have explicitly assigned 'null' to your object. It is throwing Null Reference exception.

Hope this would help.